# Get property of items in list

Tags: applescript

I want to quickly create a list of all of the names of every menu item in the menu bar tree for an app.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell first process where name is "Script Editor"
        set menuContents to entire contents of menu bar 1
        return name of menuContents
    end tell
end tell
```

This code throws error number -1728, which means the following according to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_codes.html).

> The referenced object doesn’t exist. This is a run-time resolution error, 
>   such as when attempting to reference a third object when only two
>   objects exist.

EDIT:

I'm not completely sure, but it seems that the problem arises because `entire contents` dereferences the UIElements from their source. Properties of UIElements might be referenced by pointer, which means that the UIElements don't have access to them once dereferenced.

Comment: To what end purpose are you wanting to retrieve such information and in what format?

Comment: @user3439894 I'm experimenting with reading the menus (and their properties) of various applications. I have already done it successfully using other methods, but they are quite slow compared to the speed with which `entire contents` fetches everything.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `return name of menuContents` because `menuContents`, in the context of your *code*, is a *list* and a *list object* does not have a `name` *property*.

The *properties* of a *list object* are: `class`, `length`, `rest` and `reverse`

So, any of the following are valid *commands*:

```
return class of menuContents
return length of menuContents
return rest of menuContents
return reverse of menuContents
```

The *elements* of *list objects* are: `item`

To get the `name` *property* of each `item` in the *list*, use the following example:

```
set menuNames to {}
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Script Editor"
        set menuContents to entire contents of menu bar 1
        repeat with thisItem in menuContents
            set end of menuNames to name of thisItem
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
return menuNames
```

---

See the [list class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCDBHIE) it the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html).

Comment: One of the problems I see with your solution is, for example, I have over 100 items In my "Recent Items" menu of "Apple" menu.  Your code Itemizes every one of those items as well.  Your code produced a list of almost 600 items on my system.  seems excessive to me.

Comment: @wch1zpink, You are entirely missing the point of my answer, which was to primarily show why the _code_ in the OP failed and one _example_ how to retrieve the _names_ of all the _menu items_ returned by `entire contents`. It's strictly an _example_ and not necessarily meant to be _working code_ or a solution, considering the comment exchange I had with the OP in the first place! It certainly could be coded to leave out the branches that could be long, but the point was to show why the _code_ in the OP threw an error and a way to use `entire contents` as that was what was trying to be used!

Comment: It works, but it pretty much kills the speed with which `entire contents` retrieves the menu items. It must have to do with the number of apple events it sends to System Events when getting the names.